# Measurability issue of stochastic stieltjes integration. Joint measurability of $\int_0^t F(s,\omega) dA_s(\omega)$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

This is a standard setting in stochastic stieltjes integration. I have some questions about the measurability issues in this setting.

Let $A$ be a right-continuous increasing process, i.e. the paths of $A: t \mapsto A_t(\omega)$ are non-decreasing and right-continuous. Then for a fixed $\omega$, this function induces a measure $\mu_A(\omega,ds)$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$. If $f$ is a bounded, Borel function on $\mathbb{R}_+$, then $\int_0^t f(s)\mu_A(\omega,ds)$ is well-defined for each $t>0$. We denote this integral by $\int_0^t f(s)dA_s(\omega)$. If $F_s = F(s,\omega)$ is bounded and jointly measurable, we can define, $\omega$-by-$\omega$, the integral $I(t,\omega) = \int_0^t F(s,\omega) dA_s(\omega)$. $I$ is right continuous in $t$ and jointly measurable.

In the above case, how can we explicitly show that $I$ is right continuous in $t$ and jointly measurable? It seems like the function $\omega \mapsto dA_s(\omega)$ is measurable, but I cannot find the details to these anywhere. I would greatly appreciate some formal explanations to these.

Comment: The right continuity of $I$ follows from the dominated convergence theorem, right?

Comment: @sharpe Yes I actually figured that part out just after posting this, but still not much clue about measurability.

Comment: For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $T \ge 0$, define $I_n(\cdot,\omega) = I(0,\omega)\mathbf{1}_{\{0\}}(\cdot)+\sum_{k = 1}^{2^n}I(Tk/2^n,\omega)\mathbf{1}_{ \{(T(k-1)/2^n, Tk/2^n]\}}(\cdot)$ on $[0,T]\times \Omega$. Can you show that for each $t$, the integral $I(t,\cdot)$ is measurable? If so, each $I_n$ is jointly measurable and thus $I$ is also jointly measurable because of the right continuity.

Comment: So for the first part, we need $\omega \mapsto \int_0^t g(\omega) dA_s(\omega)$ to be measurable for a bounded measurable $g$. How can we show that this is measurable? Basically each $\omega$ induces a different measure $\mu_A(\omega,ds)$. I'm not aware of any theorems which guarantee this is measurable.

Comment: For each $t$, the random variable $\omega \mapsto A_t(\omega)$ is measurable, right? Then, you'll see from the above procedure and the right continuity of $t \mapsto A_t$ that $(t,\omega) \mapsto A(t,\omega)$ is measurable. Hence, for each $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$, the map $\omega \mapsto \mu_A(\omega, (a,b])$ is  measurable.

Comment: Therefore, for any measurable function $g(\omega)$, the map $\omega \mapsto \int_{0}^t g(\omega)\,dA_s(\omega)(=g(\omega) \times \int_{0}^t \,dA_s(\omega))$ is also measurable.

Comment: @sharpe All of your argument is clear to me except for : why is the map $\omega \mapsto \mu_A(\omega, (a,b])$ meaurable if $(t,\omega) \mapsto A(t,\omega)$ is measurable?

Comment: For each $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$, $\mu_A(\omega,(a,b])$ is defined by $\mu_A(\omega,(a,b])=A_{b}(\omega)-A_{a}(\omega)$.

Comment: Please notice that the maps $\omega \mapsto A_b(\omega)$ and $\omega \mapsto A_a(\omega)$ are measurable.

Comment: @sharpe ok so in this case it doesn't seem like we need the full power of joint measurability $(t,\omega) \mapsto A(t,\omega)$?

Comment: Ah sorry! We only need the measurability of $\omega \mapsto A(t,\omega)$. This implies that $\omega \mapsto \mu_A((a,b])$ is measurable. I am sorry for confusing you.

Comment: @sharpe No I think this was my mistake and you are right! So when we look at $I(t,\cdot)$, we are actually looking at integrals $\int_0^t F(s,\omega) dA_s(\omega)$. So we need to show that $(t,\omega) \mapsto \int_0^t dA_s(\omega)$ is measurable. And this follows from $(t,\omega) \mapsto \int_0^t dA_s(\omega) = A_t(\omega) - A_0(\omega)$, which follows from joint measurability of $A$. Actually, I think this last line was all we needed since then any bounded measurable $F$ can be approximated by simple measurable functions.

Comment: Below, I summarize the above discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fot $t > 0$ and $\omega$, we define $I(t,\omega)$ as 
\begin{align*}
I(t,\omega)=\int_{0}^t F(s,\omega )\,dA_s(\omega).
\end{align*}

**Step1.**
We first show that for each $t > 0$, the map $\omega \mapsto I(t,\omega)$ is measurable. By a monotone class argument, we may assume that $F(s,\omega)=f(s)g(\omega)$ for some bounded measurable functions $f:\mathbb{R}_{+} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\Omega  \to \mathbb{R}$. Notice that for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$, the map $\omega  \mapsto \mu_A(\omega ,(a,b])$ is measurable. This together with the fact that $f$ is approximated by simple measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$, we see that the map $\omega  \mapsto \int_{0}^t f(s)\,dA_s(\omega)$ is measurable. Therefore, the map $\omega \mapsto I(t,\omega)(=g(\omega ) \times \int_{0}^t f(s)\,dA_s(\omega) )$ is also measurable.

**Step2.**
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $T>0$. For $(\omega,s) \in \Omega \times [0,T]$, we set 
\begin{align*}
I_n(t,\omega)=\mathbf{1}_{\{0\}}(t)I(0,\omega)+\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\mathbf{1}_{\{( (k-1)T/2^n, kT/2^n]\}}(t )I((k-1)T/2^n,\omega).
\end{align*}
By the dominated convergence theorem, we see that the map $t \mapsto I(t,\omega)$ is right continuous on $\mathbb{R_{+}}$, and $I(t,\omega)$ is the pointwise limit of $I_{n}(t,\omega)$. Therefore, we arrive at the conclusion from **Step1.**